# bin appearing twice in command path

Tags: path

I have been trying to run the following command:

```
 ./bin/signalp -fasta test/euk10.fsa -org euk -format short -prefix euk_10_short
```

from this directory

```
1983390@vettel:~/apps/signalp-5.0b$   pwd
/home/u1983390/apps/signalp-5.0b
```

It produces this output:

```
SignalP-5.0. Starting fasta file reading...
Total proteins read: 10.
Organism: euk.
Starting protein prediction...
2020/06/22 16:23:08 asset: open /home/u1983390/apps/signalp-5.0b/bin/bin/signalp: no such file or directory
```

The problem seems to be in the path to the executable. The path
`signalp-5.0b/bin/bin/signalp` is used when it should be `signalp-5.0b/bin/signalp`

I don't understand why it is appearing twice. If I run the command `signalp -fasta test/euk10.fsa -org euk -format short -prefix euk_10_short` the output is `signalp: command not found`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a "bash" problem; it might not even have anything to do with your Linux PATH.

It sounds like [SignalP](http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/services/SignalP/) is adding the extraneous "bin".  Perhaps you've installed it incorrectly; perhaps you're just using it incorrectly.

SUGGESTION:

Carefully review your "install" instructions, particularly the "Test SignalP" section.  For example:

> http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/services/doc/signalp-5.0.readme
>
> ```
> cd /home/u1983390/apps/signalp-5.0b
> bin/signalp -fasta test/euk10.fsa -org euk -format short -prefix euk_10_short
> bin/signalp -fasta test/euk10.fsa -org euk -format long -prefix euk_10_long
> ```

Note that these commands a) are run from your install directory, and b) do *NOT* prepend "."

Comment: I'm currently going through the install now. All I have done is download SignalIP and uncompress and untar it as explained in the install instructions. I haven't installed it globally because, so far as I understand, that is not essential. I then ran the command in the signalp-5.0b directory as instructed. I'm struggling to understand where it is I have gone wrong. Would you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Add the signalp bin path to your .bashrc or .bashprofile should solve the problem.

```
export PATH="path-to-your-signalp-download-dir/signalp-5.0b/bin:$PATH"
```